# Titlebar won't hide or show

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

The titlebar class won't hide or show like it says in the sencha docs. I'm initializing it like this

```
{
    xtype: 'titlebar',
    docked: 'top',
    hidden: true
};
```

So it starts off hidden. When I set `hidden: false` then it does show up. I have it referenced in a button where when the button is pressed it either shows or hides.

`bar.show()` and `bar.hide()` do not work. Neither does `bar.setHidden(true)` or `bar.setHidden(false)`. Neither does `bar.hidden = true` or `bar.hidden = false`. The event handler in my button does work, I have it printing a message when it's pressed.

What's the alternative to get a titlebar to disappear and reappear?

**UPDATE**

Below is the code for my object and the button listener. Here is a link to the entire class file: http://pastebin.com/tbS35Czk

My settingsbar (this is defined in another class right here: http://pastebin.com/xP5NSrb8)

```
var settingsbar = {
                xtype: 'meterreadings_settingsbar',
                docked: 'top',
                added: false
              };
```

Here is the button and listener:

```
{
   xtype: 'mbButton',
   text: 'Settings',
   align: 'right',
   listeners: {
       tap: function(source, e, eOpts) {
            if(!settingsbar.added){
                settingsbar.added = true;
                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.meterreadings_main')[0].add(settingsbar);
            }   
            else{
                if(settingsbar.hidden){
                    settingsbar.show();
                }
                else{
                    settingsbar.hide();
                }

            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code? `show` and `hide` methods should works as you want: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3cb

Comment: @Akatum yes I'll be updating my question in just a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Instead of doing

```
var settingsbar = {
                xtype: 'meterreadings_settingsbar',
                docked: 'top',
                added: false
              };
```

I needed to do

```
var settingsbar = Ext.create('pw.meterreadings.main.settingsbar.Settingsbar',{
                docked: 'top',
                added: false
              });
```

The difference is I'm using `Ext.create` instead of `xtype`.